# Dataset minus 10%

Tags: matlab

Below is a method of sampling 10% of my data:

```
%%
% Normal
normIdx = strmatch('normal.', K2);
normalSubset = cluster2(normIdx, :);
normal = randperm(size(normalSubset , 1));
p = (normal(1:3495))';

%% DoS
DoSIdx = strmatch('DoS', K2);
DoSSubset = cluster2(DoSIdx, :);
DoS = randperm(size(DoSSubset , 1));
a = (DoS(1:8))';

%%
ProbeIdx = strmatch('Probe', K2);
ProbeSubset = cluster2(ProbeIdx, :);
Probe = randperm(size(ProbeSubset , 1));
d = (Probe(1:71))';

%%
normalSample = normalSubset (p, :);
%%
DoSSample = DoSSubset (a, :);
%%
ProbeSample = ProbeSubset (d, :);

%%
idx = [normIdx(p);DoSIdx(a);ProbeIdx(d)];
%
sample = [normalSample ; DoSSample ; ProbeSample]
%
shuffle = randperm(3574);
%
TestData = sample(shuffle,:);
%
TestDataLabels = K2(idx (shuffle), :);
```

I was wondering how I could then remove this 10% from the dataset (`cluster2`)? Note that when I say 10% I have worked this out, hence (Probe(1:71) which is 10% of the probe class etc

Comment: Is there no way to do it for the full TestData? Not sure how I would get the indices for TestData but was hoping for an all in one method?

Comment: Where do `normalSample` etc come from?

Comment: Ah soz missed that bit in the code, updated question with sample subsets.

Comment: ??? Error using ==>
horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions
are not consistent.

Comment: if I try `normIdx(1:3495); DoSIdx(1:8)` then the output is a 1 dimensional (1x220000) matrix not a Nx6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF i understand it correctly, you have an index vector `idx` that contains all the rows that you want to preserve.

In this case the solution is quite simple, to remove them you can follow the approach indicated by @H.Munster, but with the correct index:

```
cluster2(idx, :) = [];
```